# Django App on Heroku :Application crashed

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-ci

guys i tried to add django to  heruko but when i tried to access my  my site through the given domain 
i have faced an issue as Application error 
here is my error log
kuapp.com request_id=3226d7fe-a42e-4c41-8618-74f00206f5af fwd="103.49.121.34" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= pr

```
otocol=https
2018-07-23T14:37:30.570428+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=m
xiondrf.herokuapp.com request_id=7bfb5e64-d420-4454-9ae2-bcc5845708f2 fwd="103.49.121.34" dyno= connect= service= status=50
3 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-23T14:38:07.207498+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=mx
iondrf.herokuapp.com request_id=7172dd6c-03e3-4b97-a671-a8955e17a9b0 fwd="88.99.195.205" dyno= connect= service= status=503
 bytes= protocol=http
2018-07-23T14:38:07.399990+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mxiondrf.her
okuapp.com request_id=5ef69e04-2675-43c3-b498-1c31b9d734cc fwd="88.99.195.205" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= pr
otocol=http
2018-07-23T14:38:10.972312+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mxiondrf.her
okuapp.com request_id=1269c22d-b338-4a5c-b3c5-eae226c0a479 fwd="103.49.121.34" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= pr
otocol=https
2018-07-23T14:38:11.368496+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=m
xiondrf.herokuapp.com request_id=fe34bf01-5208-48f5-99f1-855268cc8853 fwd="103.49.121.34" dyno= connect= service= status=50
3 bytes= protocol=https
```

any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: This doesn't explain much. There is a way to access the django logging through Heroku. I can double check in an hour or so. But try `heroku run python manage.py runserver`.

Comment: tried using python manage.py runserver but of no use

Comment: Can you show your Procfile?

Comment: i figured out the solution by adding web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT

Comment: Sorry couldn't help you sooner. Was at work. I found this solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had this very issue as well, in my case it was because my Procfile file was not capitalized as in `procfile` instead of "`Procfile`", the latter being the correct one . Also do make sure your Profile contains -

> `web: gunicorn MY_PROJECT.wsgi`